# How does Blazor resolve a nested component that has @page directive

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to understand component re-usability in Blazor.

In this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-blazor-webassembly-visual-studio-code/5-exercise-add-component), the `Counter` component [which also has a `@page` directive] is added inside the `Index` component.

So, is the `@page` directive ignored for the nested component?

**Counter**

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;  
        
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount ++;
    }
}
```

**Index**

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<Counter />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is the `@page` directive ignored for the nested component?

Yes.

There is no real distinction between Components and Pages in Blazor. As you can also tell from the Add|New menu. There is only one option.

When you add an `@page "..."` the Component becomes routable and the router will instantiate it in the `@Body` element in MainLayout.razor.

Comment: `in the @Body tag...` @Body is certainly not a tag. It is the name of a property defined on the `LayoutComponentBase` object. The `Body` property is of `RenderFragment` type, and it returns the content to be rendered inside the layout. To execute the RenderFragment property you should place the "at sign" before the name of the property.

Answer (score 1):

The `@page` directive is only for routing.  It affects nothing else about a component.  You could tile 20 pages into a single page if you had some reason to do so, simply by adding them like you would any other component.